# what is node.js equivalent to python's sys.executable

Tags: node.js

I am trying to find the node.js executable path from within javascript.

in python i can do that by `sys.executable`, looking for something similar in javascript/node.js

Do you know if there is a library/package that i can use?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, it was my fault. I think i found it: `process.execPath`

```
> process.execPath
'/home/myuser/miniconda2/envs/mynodejs10env/bin/node'
>
```